# Unexplained Invalid Syntax in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, syntax

Whenever I press F5 to run my code, an error message pops up that reads 'invalid syntax', and the space after 'True' in the following line:

```
while not chosen4 == True
```

I have no idea what is causing this error.
The rest of the source code is below:

```
import time
playAgain = False
while not playAgain == True:
    gameOver = False
    print ("""Press ENTER to begin!
""")
    input()
    print("""text""")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ("""text""")
    time.sleep (7)
    print ("""text""")
    print("""(Press a number and then ENTER!)""")
    while not gameOver == True:
        direction = input ("Your chosen action: ")
        print("You chose {0}!".format(direction))
        time.sleep (2)
        if direction == "1":
            print ("""text""")
            time.sleep (6)
            print ("""text""")
            chosen1 = False
            while not chosen1 == True:
                direction1 = input ("Your chosen action: ")
                print ("You chose {0}!".format(direction1))
                time.sleep (2)
                if direction1 == "3":
                    print ("""text""")
                    time.sleep (2)
                    print("""text""")
                    time.sleep (8)
                    print("""text""")
                    gameOver = True
                    break
                elif direction1 == "4":
                print("""text""")
                    time.sleep (3)
                    chosen4 = False
                    while not chosen4 == True
                    #The above line is where the 'invalid syntax' is.
                    direction4 = input ("Your chosen action: ")
                    print "You chose {0}!".format(chosen4)
                    time.sleep (2)
                    if chosen4 chosen4 == "7":
                        print ("text")
                        gameOver = True
                        break
                    elif chosen4 == "8":
                        print ("text")
                        gameOver = True
                        break
                    else:
                        tryagain
                else:
                    print ("""text""")
                    time.sleep (3)
        elif direction == "2":
            print ("""text""")
            time.sleep (2)
            print("""text""")
            time.sleep (3)
            print("""text""")
            chosen2 = False
            while not chosen2 == True:
                direction2 = input ("Your chosen action: ")
                print ("You chose {0}!".format(direction2))
                time.sleep (2)
                if direction2 == "5":
                    print ("""text""")
                    time.sleep (8)
                    gameOver = True
                    break
                elif direction2 == "6":
                    print ("""text""")
                    break
                else:
                    print ("""text""")
        elif direction == "0":
            print ("""text""")
        else:
            print ("""text""")
if gameOver == True:
    input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `:`
The body of the loop will need to be indented too

This indentation problem jumped out at me too

```
                elif direction1 == "4":
                print("""text""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing colon on `while not chosen4 == True`, it should be `while not chosen4 == True:`.

You are missing indentation at `elif direction1 == "4":` on the print statement below.

Also this is not an error but instead of doing `while not chosen2 == True:` change it to `while chosen == False:` or `while chosen != True:` as it helps clean it up.